# Form a grid dynamically with bottom border conditionally appearing for cells

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display the data dynamically to form a grid like -http://fiddle.jshell.net/suneelsfdc/Lx7g5m3d/2/ [With bottom margin](http://fiddle.jshell.net/suneelsfdc/Lx7g5m3d/2/)

There is a collection which I will be iterating over and displaying the data using div articleContainer. For explaining the problem, I added 5 div elements.So I am displaying bottom border for each cell such that it merges with the top border of underlying cell. But it doesn't look to be responsive. If I zoom in or zoom out, borders are no longer appearing in same line and look distorted. Can any one please suggest a responsive solution

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap is easy and responsive.Here read this [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>SemiTransparentBack</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <style type="text/css">
  body{

  }

  .back{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color: white;
    border-top:2px solid #000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px 1px 5px 0px;
  }
 </style>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="back">123</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="back">123</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="back">123</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="back">123</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="back">123</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="back">123</div>
       </div>

      </div><!--end row-->

    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.I want the layout what I have show in the fiddle - http://fiddle.jshell.net/suneelsfdc/Lx7g5m3d/2/ .But I would want it to be responsive. If you zoom out the fiddle to 25%...you see that the margins are distorted. I don't want that to happen.Is there a way we can achieve that?